# Not able to access the local file in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read the local file in client mode on Yarn framework. I was not able to access the local file in client mode also.

```
import os
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from os import listdir, path

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

import argparse
from pyspark import SparkFiles
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def main():
    spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Spark File load example") \
    .config("spark.jars","/u/user/someuser/sqljdbc4.jar") \
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true") \
    .config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled","true") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","50") \
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://******.hpc.****.com:9083") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.addFile("/u/user/vikrant/testdata/EMPFILE1.csv")


    inputfilename=getinputfile(spark)
    print("input file path is:",inputfilename)
    data = processfiledata(spark,inputfilename)
    data.show()
    spark.stop()

def getinputfile(spark):

    spark_files_dir = SparkFiles.getRootDirectory()
    print("spark_files_dir:",spark_files_dir)
    inputfile = [filename
                   for filename in listdir(spark_files_dir)
                   if filename.endswith('EMPFILE1.csv')]
    if len(inputfile) != 0:
        path_to_input_file = path.join(spark_files_dir, inputfile[0])
    else:
        print("file path not found",path_to_input_file)

    print("inputfile name:",inputfile)
    return path_to_input_file


    def processfiledata(spark,inputfilename):

        dataframe= spark.read.format("csv").option("header","false").load(inputfilename)
        return dataframe

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()

Below is my shell script-->
    spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client PysparkMainModulenew.py --files /u/user/vikrant/testdata/EMPFILE1.csv
```

Below is the error message-->

> ('spark_files_dir:',
>   u'/h/tmp/spark-76bdbd48-cbb4-4e8f-971a-383b899f79b0/userFiles-ee6dcdec-b320-433b-8491-311927c75fe2')
>       ('inputfile name:', [u'EMPFILE1.csv'])
>       ('input file path is:', u'/h/tmp/spark-76bdbd48-cbb4-4e8f-971a-383b899f79b0/userFiles-ee6dcdec-b320-433b-8491-311927c75fe2/EMPFILE1.csv')
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/u/user/vikrant/testdata/PysparkMainModulenew.py", line 57, in 
>           main()
>         File "/u/user/vikrant/testdata/PysparkMainModulenew.py", line 31, in main
>           data = processfiledata(spark,inputfilename)
>         File "/u/user/vikrant/testdata/PysparkMainModulenew.py", line 53, in processfiledata
>           dataframe = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","false").load(inputfilename)
>         File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py",
>   line 166, in load
>         File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1160, in **call**
>         File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 69, in deco  pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not
>   exist:
>   hdfs://hdd2cluster/h/tmp/spark-76bdbd48-cbb4-4e8f-971a-383b899f79b0/userFiles-ee6dcdec-b320-433b-8491-311927c75fe2/EMPFILE1.csv;'

Comment: Refer to local files using `file://`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something like this. This won't work because you need to put `PysparkMainModulenew.py` after `--files` option. So, this

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client PysparkMainModulenew.py --files /u/user/vikrant/testdata/EMPFILE1.csv
```

Should be,

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --files /u/user/vikrant/testdata/EMPFILE1.csv PysparkMainModulenew.py
```

And, No need to use `addFile` in that case. You can copy both `PysparkMainModulenew.py` and `EMPFILE1.csv` to the same folder. And, everything should be after `--files` option.

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --files /u/user/vikrant/testdata/EMPFILE1.csv /u/user/vikrant/testdata/PysparkMainModulenew.py
```

Alternatively, you can use `--py-files` option too.

Comment: Ohh.. is it because that spark context get created before it actually locate the files, hence was throwing an error.. i will try this.    Just asking.. what will happen when i run it on cluster mode.. will spark be able to relocate the local file then.

Comment: Yes, try to add it as suggested.

Comment: Can you try `sparkContext.addFile("/u/user/vikrant/testdata/EMPFILE1.csv")`, instead of `spark.sparkContext.addFile("/u/user/vikrant/testdata/EMPFILE1.csv")`?

Comment: It's not working. I got the same error. 
18/10/22 08:52:35 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/u/user/vikrant/testdata/EMPFILE1.csv does not exist

Comment: Do not specify the file inside `PysparkMainModulenew.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You can read local file only in "local" mode. If you cant to read local file in "yarn" mode then that file has to be present on all data nodes, So that when container get initiated on any of data node that file would be available to the container on that data node.

IMHO It's always better to mention technology stack version(s) and Hadoop distribution you are using in order to get swift help.

Answer (score 0):

Your default path is might be HDFS home path so for getting file from local machine you have to add `file://` in path.

```
df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header","false").load("file:///home/inputfilename")
```

Answer (score -2):

df= sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load(file:///home/inputfilename)